Was Tulsidas avatar of someone?
Tulsidas though born in 16th Century CE, wrote many works, which has risen to the status of major scriptures of Hindus.
For example - His Hanuman chalisa is used by everyone to worship Hanuman ji. Some people even consider it to be have miraculous effect.
I want to know if he was avatar of someone ?

Firstly thanks for posting your question in this forum.
Goswami Tulsidas was an incarnation of Valmiki. We can have many supporting documents for this statement. I am listing very few of them.

वाल्मीकिस्तुलसीदासः कलौ देवि भविष्यति । रामचन्द्रकथामेतां भाषाबद्धां करिष्यति ॥

(Bhavishya Purana Pratisarga 4.20).
After telling the entire story of Sri Rama, Lord Bhutabhavan Shankara says to Goddess Parvati – “O Parvati! Maharishi Valmiki will become Tulsidas in Kali Yuga and will translate this Rama Katha into Awadhi language.”

Shiva Samhitayam (Excerpted from Gita Press Gorakhpur Veda Katha Issue, page. 285).:

वाल्मीकिस्तुलसीदासः कलौ देवि भविष्यति । रामचन्द्रकथां साध्वी भाषारूपां करिष्यति ॥

Brahma Samhitayam (quoted from the Upasana Trayasiddhanta, page. 55).:

वाल्मीकिस्तुलसीदासः कलौ देवि भविष्यति । रामचन्द्रकथां साध्वी भाषारूपां करिष्यति ॥
The meaning of the above two shlokas are the same as that of the Bhavishya Purana's shloka.
"O Goddess (Parvati), in the Age of Kali, Valmiki will be re-born as Tulsidas. He will again write the story of Rama Chandra into a virtuous language."
